# Linq to entity - Call user defined method from query

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

In my project, i use several linq queries for getting prices list.
I need to calculate values based on these prices.

Is it possible to call a user method (who can, ideally, be in the entity class) directly from the linq query, for example, doing like this would be perfect

```
from foo in Foo
select new {
  price = foo.Price,
  priceclass = foo.GetClassOfPrice()
}
```

There would be no data access from GetClassOfPrice, just static code based on the price.

Thank's by advance !

Comment: yep and this don't works

Comment: That would have been valuable information to include in your question :)

Answer (score 5):

Linq-To-Entities can call only special type of methods defined in conceptual model (EDMX). These methods are called [Model defined functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456812.aspx). So if you define your method this way you [will be able to call it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456857.aspx). You can also check [this blog post](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/ef4-model-defined-functions-level-1-amp-2/).

Answer (score 4):

You can only call the method via LINQ to Objects as there is no translation to SQL for the method call.  If you materialize the query -- bring it into memory -- first, then do the selection it should work.

```
var foos = context.Foo.ToList()
                      .Select( f => new
                       {
                            price = f.Price,
                            priceClass = f.GetClassOfPrice()
                       } );
```

Note that you should perform any conditional logic (`Where`) before doing the `ToList` so that you're only transferring the data that you actually need from the DB.  I'm using extension methods because it's more natural for me and because you'd need to use the `ToList` or similar method anyway. I really dislike mixing LINQ syntax with the extension methods.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this can't be done, because your LINQ query is translated to SQL. And your method isn't known to the so called provider that does this translation.

Answer (score 1):

There are only a few functions that you can call when dealing with linq to entities and they are listed here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx